# Sencha Touch 2 - Pass value to view from controller is Error?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to use value from controller to filter store.I put this code:

**My Controller:**

```
showCatQuery: function(list,index,element,record){
        var catid = record.get('id'); << Value to pass
        this.getNavigation().push({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'A',
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            catid: catid,
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            }, 
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'showSearchCategory',
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

**My view in initialize**

```
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var sto = Ext.getStore('allapp');
        sto.clearFilter();
        sto.filter('categoryid', this.getCatid());
```

**And this Error message:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getCatid'
```

Comment: Try this.config.catid

Comment: @TDeBailleul is not Error.But is not value.is message "undefined"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sencha Touch - How to pass value in controller to store in view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146372/sencha-touch-how-to-pass-value-in-controller-to-store-in-view)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure, your View has a function called getCadid? This is what the error message is trying to tell you. You would have to make sure there is a method available while initializing.

Another, possible simpler approach is to filter the store in the controller - which would be the better approach from my perspective. The View would be able to just care about how anything is displayed and the controller cares about what data to display. 
You can use references and controls to wait for the view to finish loading and then filter the store (or wait for the user to activate custom filters, etc.):

```
Ext.define('myApp.controller.aController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        justAName: 'ViewName'
    }
    control: {
        justAName: {
             activate: 'onActivateView'
        }    
    }
}

onActivateView: function () {...}

});
```

This is the basic stub for a controller listening to the activation of a specific view. You can just get your store in this function and filter it by all data available in the controller. To get data from the View, create a reference to it, and access it in the controller via for example:

```
var data = this.getJustAnotherName().getValue();
//having a reference to a textfield for example called justAnotherName
```