# Sencha Touch 2 - Pass value from controller to view is "undefined"

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I pass value to view from controller for filter store in view.Value from controller is undefined

**My Controller:**

```
showCatQuery: function(list,index,element,record){
        var catid = record.get('id'); << Value to pass
        this.getNavigation().push({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'A',
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            catid: catid,
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            }, 
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'showSearchCategory',
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

**My view in initialize**

```
this.callParent(arguments);
        var sto = Ext.getStore('allapp');
        sto.clearFilter();
        sto.filter('categoryid', this.config.catid);
```

I put code is not error.But value is undefined.

Where code wrong ?

---

**View full Code:**

```
Ext.define('Catalog.view.showSearchCategory', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'showSearchCategory',
    requires: ['Ext.data.Store'],
    config: {

        navigationBar: false,
        items: [
            {
                title: "All Apps",
                xtype: 'list',
                // id:'Applist',
                itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/appinfos/appicons/000/000/{id}/original/{appicon_file_name}" width="50" heigh="50" style="float:left;clear:both;"></img>',
                    '<div style="margin-left: 60px;word-wrap: break-word;width:80%;">',
                    '<span style="font-size:16px;">{name}</span><br>',
                    // '<tpl for="categories">',
                    '<span style="font-size:13px;color:#7C7C7C;" id="catname">{categoryname}</span>',
                    '</div>'
                    // '</tpl>'

                ),
                store: {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    storeId: 'allapp',
                    fields: ['id','name','created_at','appicon_file_name','categoryid','categoryname','url_ios','url_android','gallery','description'],
                    sorters: [{
                        property:'created_at',
                        direction:'DESC'
                    }],
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/appinfos.json',
                        reader:{
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty:'appinfos'
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        ]       
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        console.log(this.getCatid());
        var sto = Ext.getStore('allapp');
        sto.clearFilter();
        sto.filter('categoryid', this.config.catid);
    }


});
```

---

**UPDATE**

My controller code:

```
Ext.define('Catalog.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            homepanel: 'homepanel',
            but: 'homepanel #category',
            categoryButton: 'button[action=Categories]', 
            list:'list',
            homepanellist: 'homepanel #Applist',
            navigationlist: 'navigation #Catlist',
            navigation: 'navigation'

        },
        control: {
            homepanellist:{
                itemtap: 'showApp'
            },
            categoryButton:{
                tap: 'showCat'
            },
            homepanel: {
                back: 'backButtonHandler'
            },
            navigationlist:{
                itemtap: 'showCatQuery'
            },
            navigation:{
                back: 'backButtonNav'
            }
        }
    },

    //called when the Application is launched, remove if not needed
    showApp: function(list,index,element,record) {
        Ext.getCmp('category').hide();
        // this.getBut().setHidden(true);
        var Catname = Ext.get('catname').dom.innerHTML;
        var butDown = '';
        var gal = record.get('gallery');
        var items2 = [];
        if(gal.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < gal.length;i++){
                items2.push({
                    html:'<center><img style="margin-top:10px;" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/gallery_apps/imgs/000/000/'+gal[i].id+'/original/'+gal[i].img_file_name+'" width="200" height="300"></center>'
                }) 
            } 
        }
        // Check OS Mobile
        if(Ext.os.name == "iOS"){
            butDown = "<div style='float:right;position: relative;top: -20px;'><a href='"+record.get('url_ios')+"'><img src='touch/resources/images/d_ios.png' style='width: 100px;float: right;margin-top: -15px;'></a></div>";
        }else{
            butDown = "<div style='float:right;position: relative;top: -20px;'><a href='"+record.get('url_android')+"'><img src='touch/resources/images/d_and.png' style='width: 100px;float: right;margin-top: -15px;'></a></div>";
        }
        // Check OS Mobile
        this.getHomepanel().push({ 

            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'info',
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    style: 'margin-left: -1.2em;margin-right: -1.2em;margin-top: -1.2em;',
                    height:100,
                    html: '<div style="width: 100%;height: 100px;padding: 1.2em;border-bottom:2px ridge #C5C7BC;">'+
                        '<div style="float:left;width:85px;">'+
                            '<img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/appinfos/appicons/000/000/'+record.get('id')+'/original/'+record.get('appicon_file_name')+'" width="75" heigh="75"></img>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div style="word-wrap: break-word;"><b><p style="font-size:15px;margin:0;">'+record.get('name')+'</p></b><p>'+Catname+'</p></div>'+
                        butDown+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div style="clear:both;"></div>'

                },
                {
                    // xtype:'datascreen',
                    // data:record.data
                    xtype:'carousel',
                    direction: 'horizontal',
                    height:325,
                    style: 'margin-left: -1.2em;margin-right: -1.2em;background-color:#C0C0C0;box-shadow:inset 3px 3px 49px #fafafa;border-bottom:2px ridge #C5C7BC;',
                    listeners:
                    {
                        'afterrender': function(carousel) {
                            carousel.pageTurner = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() {
                                if (this.getActiveIndex() == this.items.length - 1) {
                                    this.setActiveItem(0, 'slide');
                                }
                                else {
                                    this.next();
                                }
                                this.pageTurner.delay(6000);
                            }, carousel);
                            carousel.pageTurner.delay(6000);
                        }
                    },
                    items: items2 
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    style: 'margin-left: -1.2em;margin-right: -1.2em;',
                    html: 
                    '<div style="width: 100%;padding: 1.2em;border-bottom:2px ridge #C5C7BC;">'+
                        '<h1 style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:black;">Description</h1>'+
                        '<div id="deS">'+
                            record.get('description')+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'
                }
            ]
        });


    },
    backButtonHandler: function(button){
        Ext.getCmp('category').show();
    },
    backButtonNav: function(button){
        Ext.getCmp('category').hide();
    },
    showCat: function(btn){
        Ext.getCmp('category').hide();
        this.getHomepanel().push(
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Categories',
                scrollable: true,
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit'
                }, 
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'navigation'
                    }
                ]
            }
        );

        // this.but().setHidden(true);

    },
    showCatQuery: function(list,index,element,record){
        // var sto = Ext.getStore('myStore');
        // sto.clearFilter();
        // sto.filter('id', record.get('id'));
        // console.log(record.get('id'));
        var catid = record.get('id');
        this.getNavigation().push({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'A',
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            catid: catid,
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            }, 
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'showSearchCategory',
                }
            ]
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sencha Touch - How to pass value in controller to store in view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146372/sencha-touch-how-to-pass-value-in-controller-to-store-in-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your view has `catid` in its `config` definition, you should use the setter/getter for access to that property:

```
sto.filter('categoryid', this.getCatid());
```

Items that are added to `config` automatically have set/get created for them.

### **EDIT**

I'm adding the full view code that you should use.  The only reason `this.getCatid()` would not give your value in your `initialize` method is if you are not passing in a value.

```
Ext.define('Catalog.view.showSearchCategory', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'showSearchCategory',
    requires: ['Ext.data.Store'],
    config: {

        catid: null,

        navigationBar: false,
        items: [
            {
                title: "All Apps",
                xtype: 'list',
                // id:'Applist',
                itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/appinfos/appicons/000/000/{id}/original/{appicon_file_name}" width="50" heigh="50" style="float:left;clear:both;"></img>',
                    '<div style="margin-left: 60px;word-wrap: break-word;width:80%;">',
                    '<span style="font-size:16px;">{name}</span><br>',
                    // '<tpl for="categories">',
                    '<span style="font-size:13px;color:#7C7C7C;" id="catname">{categoryname}</span>',
                    '</div>'
                    // '</tpl>'

                ),
                store: {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    storeId: 'allapp',
                    fields: ['id','name','created_at','appicon_file_name','categoryid','categoryname','url_ios','url_android','gallery','description'],
                    sorters: [{
                        property:'created_at',
                        direction:'DESC'
                    }],
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/appinfos.json',
                        reader:{
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty:'appinfos'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(this.getCatid());
        var sto = Ext.getStore('allapp');
        sto.clearFilter();
        sto.filter('categoryid', this.getCatid());

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }


});
```

View:

```
showCatQuery: function(list,index,element,record){
    var catid = record.get('id'); 
    this.getNavigation().push({
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'A',
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        layout: {
           type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'showSearchCategory',
                catid: catid
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: Error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getCatid' "

Comment: If your view is configured with `config: {catid: null}`, then the only reason my answer would fail is if your record does not have an `id` field (in other words, `var catid = record.get('id');` is undefined).

Comment: See my previous comment... add `catid: null` to your `config` in the view and my answer should work for you.

Comment: Now.I add catid: null in my view.Value catid is "null".

Value is not catid from controller

Comment: Value is null.I passing from controller but value is not passing

see my controller code Update

Comment: Ah, you need to pass `catid` as a config param of your `showSearchCategory`, NOT your panel.  See edited answer.